# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord database query optimization for Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

There is Ruby on Rails application which connects to the PostgreSql database. In production env. it executes select query very slowly, actually it takes several minutes to load the page. In the code there are several conditions for loading objects from database. As I'm new to ROR I was wondering how sql queries are executed. For instance, if I have following code:

```
objectsList = SampleObjects.all
objectsList = objectsList.where(... some conditions...)
objectsList = objectsList.where(... another set of conditions...)
objectsList = objectsList.to_a
```

would it load all objects from the database at the first line? Or it would take into account the second line (conditions)? If I try to add `puts objectsList` after the firs line, than it shows full list of all objects from the database. When I restored the databases locally, the query execution time is normal, it takes only few seconds to execute queries and load data. My second question is whether someone else experienced such a significant performance degradation with amazon hosting? Could it be the main reason of this performance problem?

Comment: @DaveNewton You have to be very careful if you "test this for yourself in the Rails console" because the console evaluates the last expression differently than real code does. For example, `q = Model.where(...)` in the console will end up accessing the database, `q = Model.where(...); nil` in the console is a better approximation of what happens in "real" code.

Comment: Anyway, the query is executed as soon as you try to access the results, in your case that would be at `objectsList.to_a`. Until then you're just building a query. But note that `rails console` behaves differently than real code.